# Beginner In VB.Net/SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I  am an Access developer seeking to learn SQL Server Express development with VB.Net front ends. I have little knowledge of both, though I have already understood how to use linked tables from an Access front end via ODBC.

My questions are:

1.Iam confused...to program in VB.Net, which application should I download ? Visual Basic 2010/2012 or Visual Studio Express ?

2.Is it possible (and Free) to create reports in VB.Net front ends ?

3.Can I run Access reports in a VB.Net front end with an Access back-end ?

4.How does one deploy a complete multi-user VB.Net application ?

5.I have downloaded SQL Server Express 2008 R2 (with Management Studio), I just learnt there is SQL Server Express R2 with Advanced Services, which contains reporting features.How reliable or effecient are these reporting features ? Cant I create reports in SQL Server Express R2 and call them from the VB.Net front ends?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345151(v=sql.90).aspx

That will probably give you an idea of what is involved. And do you want your application to be web based or Desktop?

If you its going to be a web based application, then please download this http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web#product-express-web

Else if you want to develop it as a desktop application, then get self this http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop

Then get an express edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2012 from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx